# reading JSON data from php file in android application

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

i am just a beginner in developing android applications, i wanted to connect my application to a server so i could get data from MySQL. so i tried to make login part first but i have some problems. my code doesn't work for reading JSON.
my codes are as below:
LoginActivity(MainActivity) :

```
package ir.naserpour.sportclub;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String link;
    String response;
        //get values
        String username,password;
        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext (Context newBase){
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            //define things
            TextView menu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
            final EditText login_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
            final EditText login_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
            Button login_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_login);
            Button login_register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_register);
            CheckBox rememberme = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.login_remeberme);


        //set icon type face
        Typeface fonticon = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/icon.ttf");
        menu.setTypeface(fonticon);

        login_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                username = login_username.getText().toString();
                password = login_password.getText().toString();
                //check values
                if (username.length() <1 || password.length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fields cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //generate link
                    link = "http://localhost:8080/login.php?username="+username+"&password="+password;
                    login();
                    if(response=="true"){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if(response=="false"){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }

        @Override
        protected void onPause () {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    public String login() {

        new JSONParse().execute();
        return response;
    }

    public class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"getting data ...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(link);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {
                JSONArray result = json.getJSONArray("result");
                JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
                try {
                    String res = new String(c.getString("response").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                    response = res;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

JSONParser.java:

```
package ir.naserpour.sportclub;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

/**
 * Created by Mohammad Naserpour on 9/22/2016.
 */
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

and also my login.php script:

```
<?php
define("HOST","localhost");
define("USERNAME","root");
define("PASSWORD","");
define("NAME","users");

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,NAME);

$username = $_GET["username"];
$password = $_GET["password"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username ='$username' AND password='$password'";

$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));


if(isset($check)){
echo '{"result":[{"response":"true"}]}';
}else{
echo '{"result":[{"response":"false"}]}';
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

i would be so happy if i find out the problem. thank you.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in your solution? Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: @Egor you know, as i told i am just a basic. honestly no, i didn't but i will do next times before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) tutorial :
its a full tutorial about login process using [google volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

First : On device side, Use volley, its simple and easy to use

Second : On server, what is `{"result":[{"response":"true"}]}`

any problem with `{"result":true}` ??

Last but not the least : Did you use JSON before or this code is trial and error copy paste from some tutorials?

Comment: i tried  the second on(result : true) but i got no answers, i tried that one with a json array. last one: there were no need for json encode, so i just write it myself. i did something wrong?

Comment: first of all, you dont use jsonarray for single response. then your response will decide how you receive it on your device. if your are passing json as string then you must parse the string on device. if you send the object as json then you can directly receive it on device. latter is suggested though.